# Pass population to Genetic Algorithm

Tags: r, genetic-algorithm

I have started learning `GA` in `R`.

Given I have the below function:

```
f <- function(x)  (x^2+x)*cos(x)
min <- -10; max <- 10
curve(f, min, max, n = 1000)
```

I know, I can call GA over it using the below code:

```
library(GA)

GA <- ga(type = "real-valued", fitness = f, min = min, max = max,monitor =FALSE)

summary(GA)
```

But now, *i am wondering if i can pass a vector containing* **300** *values, and* ask `GA` *to randomly select* **100** *out the all population(300)?*

**Point:** I have read about the [ga_lrSelection](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GA/GA.pdf), but i don't know how to use them